# Add parameter to model from web

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

My problem is to check password using two fields for that  , acrually I do not understand how I cann add one more parameter to model. 
I have classes:
Customer
CustomerController
CustomerDataInitializer
CustomerManagement
RegistrationForm

I have already tried to add one more parameter(password check) to registration Fom, but acruallz I do not want to do it because then this parameter will be saved in Customer repository. I do not want it.

````
    String register(Model model, RegistrationForm form) {
        //String check_password;
        model.addAttribute("form", form);
        //String check_password = new String();
        model.addAttribute("check_password",check_password);
        return "register";
    }```

```@PostMapping("/register")
    String registerNew(@Valid RegistrationForm form, Errors result,Model model) {
        //assert model.getAttribute("check_password").equals(form.getPassword());
        if(model.getAttribute("check_password")!=form.getPassword()){
            return "register";
        }

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "register";
        }

        customerManagement.createCustomer(form);

        return "redirect:/";
    }```



    ``` <div class="field">
            <label th:text="#{register.password}" for="password">Passwort</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" th:field="*{password}" th:errorclass="fieldError" type="password"
                   required="required"/><br/>
            <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}">Das Passwort darf
                nicht leer sein.</p>
        </div>```
````

Passwort
            
            Das Passwort darf
                nicht leer sein.

```
I wish to check password for the equality
If it is not so, the error should be shown on the page
Thanks In advance
```

Comment: Your form should be related to your form, not about the actual customer. So it should be part of the form (the web part) but later on not be stored in the database.

Comment: Seems got to be, but It is nt mz code. And previous coder made so that Customer is created according the form


 ```public Customer createCustomer(RegistrationForm form) {
  Assert.notNull(form, "Registration form must not be null!");
  var password = UnencryptedPassword.of(form.getPassword());
  var userAccount = userAccounts.create(form.getName(), password, CUSTOMER_ROLE);
  return customers.save(new Customer(userAccount, form.getAddress()));

 }```

Comment: Then why would adding a field to the form, make that field part of the `Customer`? It should only map/transfer the fields it needs to create the customer. **Please don't add additional code as comments, that is totally unreadable!**. Judging what you added, just add the field to your form, it won't be part of the `Customer`. That is why you, generally, should have a seperate DTO for your web layer, to make these things possibe.

Comment: I thought that is would be easier just to add new parameter to model in get , but I need to make this variable somewhere, I can nnot just create new variable inside method

Comment: Just add a field to the form, create a validor to check equality (or in your service method). That is the easiest way, you will get binding, conversion, error translation etc. If you don't you will have to do that yourself.

Comment: Now I wiill try, thanks